# How to get users click in calendar view to be stored as dd/mm/yyyy in SQLite

Tags: java, android, date

In my SQLite database I have my dates stored in this format 02/01/2023 but when I try to get the date from the calendarview it gives them to me as 2/1/2023 which causes me to have an error when trying to retrieve the data from the database that matches that date.

How do I format this into a String variable?

My attempt so far:

```
    public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView calendarview, int i, int i1,int i2) {
        exercise_name = new ArrayList<>();
        set_weight = new ArrayList<>();
        set_reps = new ArrayList<>();
        set_date= new ArrayList<>();
    //formatting to dd/mm/yyyy
            System.out.println("both are over 10");
            date =    i2 + "/" + (i1+1) + "/" + i;

        //month needs plus 1 because it starts at 0
        tviewdate.setText(date);
        storeDataDateinArrays();
```

Comment: have you tried applying a dateformatter?

Comment: I believe that the standard format in [SQLite is YYYY-MM-DD](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), also known as ISO 8601. I would certainly use it. It is also the default format for `LocalDate`, which makes it easy to format it for your user the way they prefer to see it, for example dd/mm/yyyy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a better way (than what you have posted as an answer) to get the required formatted string:

```
String output = String.format("%02d/%02d/%d", day, month, year);
```

where `day`, `month` and `year` are integers.

### Using `java.time` API:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu");

        // Sample units
        int year = 2023, month = 2, day = 1;
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(year, month, day);
        String output = date.format(formatter);
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
01/02/2023
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/2um1Dl)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Comment: Good answer. I suspect that the OP’s date picker uses 0-based month numbers (0 = January through 11 = December), so they will probably need a simple conversion.

Comment: the demo is really helpful. other answers are also good, but I think this one is the most complete

Answer (score 2):

This is how i got it to work:

```
        String sYear = String.valueOf(Year);
        String sMonth = String.valueOf((Month + 1));
        String sDay = String.valueOf(Day);

        if (sDay.length() == 1)
            sDay = "0" + sDay;

        if (sMonth.length() == 1)
            sMonth = "0" + sMonth;

        if (sDay.length() == 1)
            sDay = "0" + sDay;

            date =   sDay + "/" + sMonth + "/" + sYear;
```

Comment: Way too manual. Use a formatter. See the other answer.